# Registering Third-Party Vue Components in Laravel

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm new to using Vue.js with Laravel and there is one thing I couldn't figure out.

When I write my own components, I know how to implement and register them into my project by using the `app.js` file.

My question is, how can I register third party components into Laravel? I'm trying to register [Vue Form Wizard](https://cristijora.github.io/vue-form-wizard) into my project, but I can't get it to work.

I've tried multiple ways to register the component:

```
// app.js file

require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('form-wizard', require('./components/FormWizard.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

My component file:

```
<script>
    import VueFormWizard from 'vue-form-wizard';
    import 'vue-form-wizard/dist/vue-form-wizard.min.css';
    Vue.use(VueFormWizard)
</script>
```

My view called like so:

```
<form-wizard 
    @on-complete="onComplete"
    color="#FFA500"
    error-color="#a94442"
    shape="tab"
    next-button-text="Continue"
    back-button-text="Previous"
    finish-button-text="Complete"
></form-wizard>
```

What do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: Check that answer explaining Laravel Horizon way https://stackoverflow.com/a/60350757/2682025

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to define a `FormWizard` component. Simply move the code in the `script` section of your component file to the `app.js` file:

```
// app.js file
require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue = require('vue');

import VueFormWizard from 'vue-form-wizard';
import 'vue-form-wizard/dist/vue-form-wizard.min.css';
Vue.use(VueFormWizard)

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

This will register the `VueFormWizard` component globally, meaning you can use the `form-wizard` tag in any template.

Comment: Thanks! Now I have a working copy of the component. Yet I have another problem now. I registered two components the way you described and they are working fine separately. But when I put one inside another like: <form-wizard><another-component></another-component></form-wizard> it is not working.

Comment: That is a separate issue. You should read through the documentation for this component and if you can't figure it out post another question.

Comment: Thanks for your help!